# Access a predefined child object from its parent object with a string

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object that has been returned from a Database.

I want to build a function that, if passed a parent object and a string, can return a child from the parent with the same name as the string.

the following code obviously does not work, but gives the idea:

```
function filter (object,  text) {  
return object.Text  
}
```

such that

```
var object = {
    "prop1": 1,
    "prop2": 
        {
            "ChildProp1": 1,
            "ChildProp2": 2,
        }
}
var text = "prop2"

var ChildObject = filter(object, text)

//expected content of ChildObject = {
//            "ChildProp1": 1,
//            "ChildProp2": 2,
//        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need a function to access a property by name; it’s a fundamental part of JavaScript’s syntax.

```
object[text]
```

Comment: Thank you for the straightforward answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
function filter(object, text) {  
    return object[text];
}
```

This allows you to dynamically access a property with bracket notation, instead of statically accessing one with dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

Just use array syntax,

```
Object["property"]
```

Comment: It’s not called array syntax.